# Is there a shorter way of writing $(document) in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is there a shorter way of writing $(document) in jQuery.  I'm replacing all my

```
$("#id").live(...)
```

function calls for

```
$(document).on("touchstart click" ...)
```

and want to save valuable keypresses.

Comment: JavaScript has the concept of **variables**: `var $d = $(document);` ;)

Comment: Are you only allowed so many key presses per day? Are you fired for inefficiency if you go over?

Comment: You can use a one letter variable: `var d = $(document);`

Comment: @JustinSatyr Yes, I constantly hit the cap. ;)

Comment: Many text editors have a replace/replace all feature that should save you a few of those keystrokes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could cache it in a variable:

```
var $d = $(document);
```

then simply use `$d` in place of it elsewhere in your code. So:

```
$d.on('events', 'selector', function() {...});
```

However, when using `.on()` you should ideally bind the event handlers on static elements closer to the dynamic elements than the document, so it doesn't have to travel so far up the DOM tree before being handled.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Is there a massive performance gain on attaching to static elements closer to the dynamic element?